# Changing streaming frame rate for BlueFox3 camera using c++ (Linux)?

Tags: c++, linux, camera, matrix-vision

I did not find how to set from a C++ code the number of frames per second the camera needs to acquire. The provide API https://www.matrix-vision.com/manuals/SDK_CPP/classmvIMPACT_1_1acquire_1_1CameraSettingsBlueCOUGAR.html#ab32a40c6266ca694210e99438a459784 is far from being clear.

The API only refers to `frameRate_Hz` variable without telling how to set it...

Has anyone an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Same way you set any other property with the API:

```
((CameraSettingsBlueFOX*)cam)->frameRate_Hz.write(30.0);
```